# Openshift Wildfly 10 restarts automatically due to Out Of Memory error

Tags: java, openshift, heap-memory, activemq-artemis, wildfly-10

OpenShit Prouction App is restarting automatically daily once due to heap space error even though i haven't configured a message broker in my application, i found activemq is trying create new thread getting heap space error though my logs.

Should we explicitly disable activemq?

```
[31m01:34:12,417 ERROR [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client] (Thread-114 (ActiveMQ-remoting-threads-ActiveMQServerImpl::serverUUID=54cb8ef9-d17a-11e5-b538-af749189a999-28800659-992791)) AMQ214017: Caught unexpected Throwable: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: unable to create new native thread
    at java.lang.Thread.start0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Thread.start(Thread.java:714)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.addWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:950)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.execute(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1357)
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.utils.OrderedExecutorFactory$OrderedExecutor.execute(OrderedExecutorFactory.java:85)
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.remoting.impl.invm.InVMConnection.write(InVMConnection.java:163)
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.remoting.impl.invm.InVMConnection.write(InVMConnection.java:151)
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.protocol.core.impl.ChannelImpl.send(ChannelImpl.java:259)
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.protocol.core.impl.ChannelImpl.send(ChannelImpl.java:201)
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.protocol.core.ServerSessionPacketHandler.doConfirmAndResponse(ServerSessionPacketHandler.java:579)
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.protocol.core.ServerSessionPacketHandler.access$000(ServerSessionPacketHandler.java:116)
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.protocol.core.ServerSessionPacketHandler$1.done(ServerSessionPacketHandler.java:561)
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.persistence.impl.journal.OperationContextImpl.executeOnCompletion(OperationContextImpl.java:161)
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.persistence.impl.journal.JournalStorageManager.afterCompleteOperations(JournalStorageManager.java:666)
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.protocol.core.ServerSessionPacketHandler.sendResponse(ServerSessionPacketHandler.java:546)
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.protocol.core.ServerSessionPacketHandler.handlePacket(ServerSessionPacketHandler.java:531)
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.protocol.core.impl.ChannelImpl.handlePacket(ChannelImpl.java:567)
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.protocol.core.impl.RemotingConnectionImpl.doBufferReceived(RemotingConnectionImpl.java:349)
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.protocol.core.impl.RemotingConnectionImpl.bufferReceived(RemotingConnectionImpl.java:331)
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.remoting.server.impl.RemotingServiceImpl$DelegatingBufferHandler.bufferReceived(RemotingServiceImpl.java:605)
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.remoting.impl.invm.InVMConnection$1.run(InVMConnection.java:171)
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.utils.OrderedExecutorFactory$OrderedExecutor$ExecutorTask.run(OrderedExecutorFactory.java:100)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: The place where the JVM runs out of memory is by no means necessary the place that is leaking memory. Its just where the gas tank ran dry. Or did you see this happening repeatedly on several restarts?

Comment: as per last one week logs daily i am finding once in each day log

Comment: I would rather report this somehow, as this is might still only be a symtom of a bigger problem, turning it off and ignoring it is not going to give you a guarantee of stability. I already find it amazing that Wildfly 10 is in there, that was only released like a week ago. I wouldn't call that production ready.

Answer (score 1):

You could take a look at this [comment](https://github.com/openshift-cartridges/openshift-wildfly-cartridge/issues/32#issuecomment-67836450) on Wildfly openshift cartridge project open issues.

To summarize, some users have experienced memory, performance issues with this cartridge default settings.
This is particularly due to the fact that Openshift Wildfly cartridge enables Java EE 7 Full Profile by default (with a custom standalone.xml configuration file, not the standalone-full.xml as in default wildfly standalone configuration), which does not work well on small gears due to their limitations.

But a lot of Java EE 7 users only use Web Profile and do not need to enable all Java EE 7 Full Profile specs in their application actually.

So by enabling only Java EE 7 Web profile features and disabling Full Profile specific ones, such as messaging subsystem, you can make this cartridge work fine on a small gear.

See also this [other comment](https://github.com/openshift-cartridges/openshift-wildfly-cartridge/issues/32#issuecomment-149360096) for solution details and this [table](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY10/Getting+Started+Guide?_sscc=t) which lists differences between Java EE 7 profiles.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running this on a small gear, that is your issue.  WildFly 10 uses quite a bit of memory just by itself.  You should run it on a medium or large gear.  You can also try changing the amount of memory on the gear that is available to the JVM: https://developers.openshift.com/en/wildfly-jvm-memory.html

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `-Dactivemq.artemis.client.global.thread.pool.max.size=20`.

The default global thread pool used by Artemis client is 500 but the small gears have a thread limit of 250 threads. I had similar problem when I started 8 Wildfly instances on my Linux machine where was 4096 threads per user. Next day there was always java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: unable to create new native thread. I observed that artemis creates constantly new threads until it reaches 500.

Comment: could you give a little more details as to why one would do this? what's it for? what's it prevent?

Answer (score 0):

When you run Wildfly with standalone-full.xml configuration, you have the JMS subsystem enabled. Wildfly 10.0.0.Final has a default Artemis's thread pool initialized with 500 threads. In future versions, it will be changed with a custom thread pool.
With Wildfly 10.0.0.Final, the simple way to say to Artemis initializes a minor number of threads (as Andrsej Szywala says) is with a command line parameter at startup like this:

```
sh standalone.sh -c standalone-full-ha.xml -Dactivemq.artemis.client.global.thread.pool.max.size=30
```

You can read more in my post at jboss forum:

https://developer.jboss.org/thread/268397